# c# How to get info about a computer using IP address

Tags: c#, .net, tcp

I want to get information about a computer using an IPv4 address. Currently, I can only get the name and IPv4. But I want:
IPv4,
IPv6,
MAC,
Name,
info about OS,
etc. How can I do this? Also sorry if this is a duplicate.

Edit: Here is the code I use to get info(I had to translate it)

```
public static string[] PingPC(string address, string data)
    {
        string[] info = new string[5];
        try
        {
            Ping pingSender = new Ping();
            PingOptions options = new PingOptions();
            options.DontFragment = true; 

            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            int timeout = 100;
            PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(address, timeout, buffer, options); 

            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                info[0] = reply.Address.ToString();

                IPHostEntry hostentry = Dns.GetHostEntry(info[0]);
                info[1] = hostentry.HostName;

                info[2] = reply.Buffer.Length.ToString();
                info[3] = reply.Options.Ttl.ToString();
                info[4] = reply.RoundtripTime.ToString();

                return info;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new CantPingException();
        }

        return info;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to get the name and IP address?

Comment: @preciousbetine I edited the post

Comment: @D3DS1R: You can't get these information off the other machine which are pinging. If you could, the concept of computer security would be violated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `WMI` from which you can gain access to a wide range of information regarding a PC. Such information include CPU Serial Number, Build Number, System Serial Number, etc. You just have to find the right object and write the right query. Since the context of this topic is very large, I will only provide an example which can help you get some idea over using WMI, and you should look up what you need in MSDN documentation.

```
ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("win32_processor");
ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();

foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
{
     var processorId = mo.Properties["processorID"].Value.ToString();
     break;
}
```

Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/operating-system-classes) for more information.

In accordance with MSDN, the following class gives you information about these:

```
[Dynamic, Provider("CIMWin32"), UUID("{8502C4C0-5FBB-11D2-AAC1-006008C78BC7}"), AMENDMENT]
class Win32_NetworkAdapter : CIM_NetworkAdapter
{
  string   AdapterType;
  uint16   AdapterTypeID;
  boolean  AutoSense;
  uint16   Availability;
  string   Caption;
  uint32   ConfigManagerErrorCode;
  boolean  ConfigManagerUserConfig;
  string   CreationClassName;
  string   Description;
  string   DeviceID;
  boolean  ErrorCleared;
  string   ErrorDescription;
  string   GUID;
  uint32   Index;
  datetime InstallDate;
  boolean  Installed;
  uint32   InterfaceIndex;
  uint32   LastErrorCode;
  string   MACAddress;
  string   Manufacturer;
  uint32   MaxNumberControlled;
  uint64   MaxSpeed;
  string   Name;
  string   NetConnectionID;
  uint16   NetConnectionStatus;
  boolean  NetEnabled;
  string   NetworkAddresses[];
  string   PermanentAddress;
  boolean  PhysicalAdapter;
  string   PNPDeviceID;
  uint16   PowerManagementCapabilities[];
  boolean  PowerManagementSupported;
  string   ProductName;
  string   ServiceName;
  uint64   Speed;
  string   Status;
  uint16   StatusInfo;
  string   SystemCreationClassName;
  string   SystemName;
  datetime TimeOfLastReset;
};
```